# Run multiple servers with interconnection on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are developing applications and devices that communicate with our servers. We have one "main" Java Spring server which handles almost all the HTTP requests including user authentication, storing relevant user data and giving that data to the applications. Furthermore, we have a few smaller HTTP servers (written in golang) which are both used by the "main" server to perform certain tasks but also have some public API's that apps and devices use directly.

In our current non-production setup we run all the servers locally on one machine with an apache2 in front which directs the requests. So the servers can be accessed via the apache2 by a user by their respective subdomains but they also perform some communication between each other. When doing so, currently we simply send the request to `localhost:{PORT}` since they all run on the same machine. They furthermore all utilize the same mysql-server running on that same machine.

We are now looking to get it more production-ready and are looking to deploy it to AWS. They are currently not containerized so a solution that requires containerization (ECS? K8s?) would most likely require more work. What would be the most straightforward way to do the following:

- Deploy a number of servers on AWS where they are exposed publicly with their respective domains but can also communicate internally with one another (or would they just communicate with one another using their public domains?)
- Deploy a managed SQL database (Amazon RDS?) which is accessible for all the servers.
- Setup the routing of the requests. Currently run our own configured apache2 but I assume we can add a managed API Gateway in AWS and configure it for our servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q.  Deploy a number of servers on AWS where they are exposed publicly
>   with their respective domains but can also communicate internally with
>   one another (or would they just communicate with one another using
>   their public domains?)

On AWS you create a VPC(1st default VPC is created when you login for the first time).

*You can deploy a number of EC2 instances(virtual servers) with just private IP addresses and without any public access and put them behind an ELB(elastic load balancer). The ELB will take all the traffic and distribute the load onto the servers based on endpoint.
However the EC2 instances won't have public IPs A VPC(virtual Private Gateway) allows your services to communicate to each other via private IPs (something like 172.31.xx.xx), You can also provide domain/sub-domain names to these private IP addresses using Route53 service of AWS.*

For example You launch 2 servers:

1. Your Java Application - on 172.31.1.1 (you name it
   xyz.myjavaapp.something.com on Route53)
2. Your Angular Application - on 172.31.1.2

The angular application can reach your java application on `172.31.1.1:8080` or

```
xyz.myjavaapp.something.com:8080
```

> Q. Deploy a managed SQL database (Amazon RDS?) which is accessible for
>   all the servers.

Yes you can deploy an SQL database on RDS and it will be available to the EC2 instances. Just make sure you create proper security groups to allow only your servers to access it, and not leave it open for public internet.
Example for a VPC only security group entry is `172.31.0.0/16` This will allow only ther servers in you VPC to connect to the RDS DB. given that your VPC subnet has the range 172.31.x.x

> Q. Setup the routing of the requests. Currently run our own configured
>   apache2 but I assume we can add a managed API Gateway in AWS and
>   configure it for our servers.

You can set up public/private APIs and manage different endpoints using API Gateway.
Another way it to put your application server behind an Application ELB. The ELB can take care of load balancing as well as endpoint management.
for example  : 
  if you decide to deploy 2 servers for /getData and 1 server for /doSomethingElse. It can be easily managed by ELB.

I would suggest you use at-least servers for critical services and load balance them behind and ELB for production env.

**On another note, containerizing and deploying to kubernetes is not that difficult or time consuming. But yes it has got some learning curve, but the benefits outweigh it.
Feel free to ask questions.**

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah, not sure about k8s, used it quite a bit at previous job but feels like somewhat of an overshoot for just 3-4 svces. 

But an example setup for 4 different servers like what you suggested would be:

1) 4 elastic beanstalk apps (in their own envs). I've used EB previous for singleservers and it felt pretty straight forward to get up and running.

2) 1 ELB for the apps or do I need one ELB for every app? And if so, do I need an API gateway to point to all the ELBs?

3) 1 RDS with correct security groups. Can instances get SQL username etc from env var?

Comment: This article : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/using-api-gateway-as-a-single-entry-point-for-web-applications-and-api-microservices/     should give you an idea of API gateway with multiple services.
You essentially will need an ALB each service only if you are deploying multiple instances for each service. If you are deploying single instance, just use API Gateway.
The best way to pass credentials to your apps would be via a deployment pipeline to the env vars .